# Im seeing bug textures on my new 32x32 texture pack

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm seeing pink and black tiles and some weird half/half of other blocks combined.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about asking for a texture for a texture pack.

Comment: Can you post a picture?

Comment: FireStrike289's Steps worked

Comment: Misread the question :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is install McPatcher, there will be instructions to install texture bug fixes and then. It should work. If it's not working after that then use 32x32.